# firebase admin sdk getUserByEmail google provider - user-not-found

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Creating custom token to add my custom claims. Firebase is configured to have password and google provider.
For Google signin here is the flow -

1. Using manual google signin
2. After signin get the id_token
3. send it to my node server for custom token generation.
4. Once i have id_token on node, i get the email id of user
5. check if the user already exists in firebase, by using admin sdk
   `getUserByEmail`

I am getting user-not-found for users with Google provider, i see the users in firebase console, but not able to get it in admin sdk

Answer (score 0):

The admin API getUserByEmail only looks up by top level email, which is the currentUser.email. Make sure that is set. You may be using the "multiple accounts per email" setting which only sets the google email in currentUser.providerData and not currentUser.email.

Comment: Then in that case how do we find users with google provider(or any provider) by email(or name etc)?

Comment: "multiple accounts per email" is not the default option in Firebase Auth. If you want to lookup users by email, you will likely get multiple users as you could have a password user, facebook, google, etc with the same email and different UID. I think in that case you may have to maintain your own lookup index. (email: [list of uids])